# Can I create a PagedListPager that does not call a function

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm trying to managed a list using ajax calls, on the 1st load everything is fine as the search button makes the ajax call which loads the 1st page of results. Problem is when I create the PagedListPager it is calling the controller function with causes the page to reset and the results to disappear.

So what I would like to do is create the PagedListPager as just buttons with no actions, and handle the clicks on those buttons using Javascript. Does anybody know a way to go about this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution for this using the PagedListPager. The PagedListPager creates an unordered list, which I recreated in the view with a blank link like so:

```
<a href="">/</a>
```

This is useful, because it maintains the styles used on other PagedLists on the site.Then from javascript, override the li click event, like so:

```
 $(document).on("click", "li", function (event)
```

Now I can make ajax calls from each li without the page refreshing every time.
Hope this helps some people!!

A more elegant solution is to create the list with an id

```
<ul id="pagingbuttons" class="pagination">
```

And also give ids to the li elements inside the list.
So now from javascript override the click event just of that list like this

```
 $(document).on('click', '#pagingbuttons', function(event)
```

Then we any button is clicked you can get its id value like so

```
event.target.text
```

This stops any other li elements on the same page to fire the ajax call unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript library (which I wrote): https://github.com/pjbonestroo/PagedList

It solves the problem of reloading, pagination, etc, and is fully customizable. It includes documentation.

It will automatically call your controller function with an ajax call, or you can add data on client-side, if you prefer.

It also has some nice features like

- filtering and sorting (client- or server-side, as preferred)
- debouncing to prevent too many refreshes
- customizable buttons and styling, dependent on row-data
- easily add/remove event-listeners to rows (and get the row-data on triggering)

Regarding your question, have a special look to the customizable buttons, so that you handle the clicks on the buttons using Javascript.